# GetType from object is returning RuntimeType

Tags: c#

I have a simple function:

```cs
public string getType(object obj) {
    Type type = obj.getType();
    return type.FullName;
}
```

If you use this function on a string object, which was created on runtime, the function returns "System.RuntimeType"...

But it should return "System.String"...

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us what is calling your `getType` method, and exactly what is passed to it.

Comment: To the typeOf method is any object passed, that can be created. e.g. string, int, MyClass1, MyClass2...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you call it like this -

```
string a = "";
string type = getType(a);
```

It will return `System.String`

But if you call like this -

```
string a = "";
string type = getType(a.GetType());
```

Then it will return `System.RuntimeType`

Also, there is small `typo` in your method -

`Type type = obj.getType();` should be `Type type = obj.GetType();`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you called it like this: `getType(typeof(string))`. `typeof(abc)` is a value of type `Type` (or `RuntimeType` which is an implementation detail).

Call it like this:

`getType("")`