# Do all Type classes inherit from RuntimeType?

Tags: c#, reflection, portable-class-library

I want to know whether a on object of type `Type` is actually a type for a normal class (e.g. `Object`, `Int32`, etc.) or a type for a meta-object (e.g. `typeof(Object)`, `typeof(Int32)`, etc.).

By *type of an object* I mean:

```
Type t = typeof(Object);
Console.WriteLine("Type is {0}", t.FullName);
```

> Type is System.Object

And by *type of a type object*, i.e. *meta-object*:

```
Type t = typeof(Object).GetType();
Console.WriteLine("Type is {0}", t.FullName);
```

> Type is System.RuntimeType

I couldn't find any method/property in `Type` or `TypeInfo` to tell whether the object for which a `Type` object is made is actually a `Type` rather than a normal object.

If I have the object, I could do that:

```
bool IsType(object o) { return o is Type; }
```

But, I don't have the object itself, only its type.

I was hoping for something along the lines:

```
bool IsType(Type t) { return t.GetTypeInfo().IsType; }
```

But there's nothing like it, it seems..

So the only thing I can think of so far is:

```
bool IsType(Type type)
{
    // Can't use typeof(RuntimeType) due to its protection level
    Type runtimeType = typeof(Object).GetType();
    return runtimeType.Equals(type);
}
```

Yet, I can't be sure that `GetType()` for all objects of type `Type` would return `RuntimeType`, nor that they actually inherit from it...

### Update

Let me explain it better. I'm writing a serializer. When serializing a class member (e.g. a field or a property), I'll have the field type (yet not the object). It's perfectly possible the member to be of type `Type`.  I'd like to be able to serialize those objects as well.

For example a class like so:

```
class MyClass {
    private Type _cachedType;
}
```

I'll get the Type of the field `_cachedType` through reflection. How will I know that the object is a `Type` in the first place?

Comment: Why do you care? RuntimeType is an implementation detail of the current version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between System.Type and System.RuntimeType in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737840/whats-the-difference-between-system-type-and-system-runtimetype-in-c) | [GetType from object is returning RuntimeType](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997946/gettype-from-object-is-returning-runtimetype)

Comment: `How will I know that the object is a Type in the first place?` well, it clearly is because the variable is typed `Type`. Why don't you serialize _cachedType.FullName or something like that? Why do you need to know the exact object type?

Comment: @usr, because I have serializers for different types. Depending on the type of the field, you'd be serializing it in a different way, *obviously*.

Comment: How will you serialize a `RuntimeType` differently from any other `Type` (e.g. a `TypeBuilder`)? There aren't many meaningful derived classes of `Type`. I don't know of any that would matter.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question? Do you want to know how to identify fields that are of type `Type`?

Comment: @usr. Precisely. If they are of type `Type`, then I can simply serialize them as strings using `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`, and deserialize them with the same string using `Type.GetType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the entire question reduces to

> How can I determine that a field is of type `Type`?

As far as I can tell you don't care about the actual type of the values stored there because you will serialize all of them the same way ("then I can simply serialize them as strings using Type.AssemblyQualifiedName").

Here you go:

```
bool IsType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(Type);
}
```

No need for a subclass check. The actual objects will be of a subclass but the field will have type `Type`.

You *can* add the subclass check if you like:

```
bool IsType(Type type)
{
    return typeof(Type).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

Comment: Directly, comparing with `typeof(Type)` is so simple, I didn't think of it. Thanks. Meanwhile, I forgot to mention that it's for a portable library, I'd have to use `TypeInfo` rather than `Type` for `IsAssignableFrom`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the direct comparison doesn't appear to work for me, because `typeof(Type)` appears to return `Type`, while, Object.GetType() for an object of type `Type` returns `RuntimeType`... See here for what I mean: http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=38352

Comment: Yeah, you need to use the field type which is FieldInfo.FieldType. If you have to use the object type then use the IsAssignableFrom check.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I could use `TypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom`.

```
bool IsType(Type type)
{
    TypeInfo info = typeof(Type).GetTypeInfo();
    return info.IsAssignableFrom(type.GetTypeInfo());
}
```

Which is roughly the equivalent of using the `is` operator on an object, but this type it's a runtime type.